# Ruby on Rails: How to connect a user's application to their profile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a platform where a user has to submit an application and fill out a profile form separately.

On the platform, there is one page with links to everyone's profiles and another page with links to everyone's applications.

I want to add a link to each person's profile that takes them to their application, and also add a link to each person's application that links them to their profile.

I have two sets of models/controllers/views for user applications and profiles. Is there a way to create these links by searching for the app/profile with corresponding names?

Like for example, on a certain user's application, have a link that essentially does "link to the profile that has the same first and last name attribute as this current user's application"?

My best guess is along the lines of:

```
@user_application = UserApplication.find{ |x| x.last_name == 
@user_profile.last_name && x.first_name == @user_profile.first_name}
```

This works to some extent, but if a user created an application and forgot to create a profile or didn't create one yet, it leads to an error page. can anyone help?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html user has_one: :profile

Answer (score 0):

You should setup an association between the models. The docs on associations can be found [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

In your setup, you'll likely want the following:

```
# user.rb
has_one :profile
has_one :user_application

# user_application.rb
belongs_to :user

# profile.rb
belongs_to :user
```

You'll then need to add a `user_id` column to the `user_application` and `profile` models using the terminal:

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_user_applications user_id:integer:index
rails g migration add_user_id_to_profiles user_id:integer:index
rails db:migrate
```

Then, when users are creation their profiles / applications, in your controllers you can adjust the actions to something like the below:

```
def new
  @profile = current_user.build_profile
end

def create
  @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
  # etc ...
end
```

Finally, you'll be able to link directly to a user's profile / application using the following in your views:

```
<% if current_user.profile %>
  <%= link_to 'Profile', profile_path(current_user.profile) %>
<% end %>
```

(And obviously similar for user_profiles.)

If you don't have a `current_user` method (which is pretty standard practice), you can access via the profile or application, e.g. `profile.user.user_application`.

I'd make this [safe](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) by adding a conditional as you'll get a `NilClass` error if the (in this case) `user_application` is missing, and use `if profile.user&.user_application...`.

This question is pretty broad, so that's an overview - hope it helps. My recommendation would be to try implementing it and ask a new question if you run into any problems down the line. Hope it works out well!

Comment: This this help at all @ronsha?